# Redirecting without showing the new URL á la [PT]

Tags: mod-rewrite, apache2

I have an Apache server running on Linux. On the same host I'm running Xen with Windows Server 2008 + IIS. Windows gets a different IP address.

The host lives behind a NAT and I've configured it to direct port 80 to Linux and 8080 to Windows.

Apache offers a virtual host to handle incoming requests but these need to just be redirected to IIS, therefore my rewrite rule can be expressed as follows:

```
<VirtualHost ...>
ServerName www.firstdomain.com
...
RewriteEngine On
RewriteOptions Inherit
RewriteRule ^/(.*) http://www.seconddomain.com:8080/$1 [R,L]
```

This works fine since a request for `www.seconddomain.com` comes into the Apache VH, which rewrites the URL as `www.secondomain.com:8080` and thus the browser now lands on IIS.

My question: I don't want the user to see that the URL changed; I want it to behave the way that the passthrough option for rules works.

How can I accomplish this? And, if rewrite rules is the wrong approach, what is a better one?

**Update**

I found the [P]roxy flag for rules.  This (almost) works great.  I can put a file in the root of my IIS and reach it via `http://www.seconddomain.com/tst.html` - however, references within the document don't get redirected properly e.g. the `<img src='/images/tst.jpg' />` fails, showing there should have been an image in its place... what else do I need?

Comment: It's called [Reverse Proxy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_proxy). Check these links: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/proxy.html AND http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html . Unfortunately I have never worked with them myself and cannot really put this as an answer (which would require more details than this small comment). BTW, consider [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com/) as a place to ask proxy questions -- it's more appropriate place.

Comment: You will need `ProxyPassReverse` directive to fix such broken URLs

Comment: @LazyOne, thanks... I solved my problem but thanks for suggesting Reverse Proxy.  I'm looking into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, it all works.  I was just being dumb.  the [P] is exactly what I needed.